# Modular transformation in terms of generators

Tags: theta-functions, modular-forms

I was looking for a "general" modular transformation for the first kind of Jacobi theta function, $\theta_1(u,\tau)$. I do know how this theta function transforms under the two generators of modular transformations,
$$T:\tau\to\tau+1\quad\mbox{and}\quad S:\tau\to-\frac{1}\tau,$$
so in order to find the general formula for 
$$\tau\to\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}\quad\mbox{where}~~a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z~~\mbox{and}~~ad-bc=1,$$
I thought I need to figure out how the general modular transformation is written in terms of the above two generators. Using the Euclidean algorithm, I could find a general combination of $T$ and $S$ that gives
$$\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}\to\frac{a'\tau}{c'\tau+d}$$
but that was the best I could do...

I would really appreciate if you help me to figure out the general modular transformation for $\theta_1(u,\tau)$! (I searched for the formula first but I couldn't find it anywhere.)

Comment: Then $a' d = 1$ and you are done as  $T S^{c'} T\frac{a'\tau}{c'\tau+d} = T S\frac{c'\tau+1}{-\tau} =T S^{c'}[ -c'-\frac{d}{\tau}] = T \frac{-1}{\tau} = \tau$

Comment: Also it is not clear what you meant with Jacobi's theta function. $\theta(\tau) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{2 i \pi n^2 \tau}$ is $1$-periodic and $\theta(-1/4\tau) = (4 \tau)^{1/2} \theta(\tau)$ is modular of weight $1/2$ for $\Gamma_0(4)$ not $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}) = \Gamma_0(1)$. The theta function in $2$ variables transforms under the Heisenberg group acting on $\mathbb{H} \times \mathbb{C}$

Comment: To reuns: Thanks for your answer! I absolutely forgot a'd=1... And I think the theta function I meant is more likt the $\theta_11$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function.

Comment: Yes that's what I talked about. An example of modular form for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is the Eisenstein series. See [Diamond](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Fred%20Diamond%20Jerry%20Shurman%20A%20First%20Course%20in%20Modular%20Forms.pdf)'s book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the closed and quite explicit form for a general theta-transformation in https://doi.org/10.1017/S0308210512001023. I honestly don't know how the formula had been derived there. Seems there are also lot of new formulas there you may be interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the link!